# Converting dates with "unconventional" formats

Tags: r

I am not too great with manipulating dates in `R`, and am currently stuck on trying to convert a date that has an *ambiguous* format into a `Date` object. My dates are in the format `20150122`, for example. When I use `as.Date`, I get an error like:

`d7$Search.Date <- as.Date(d7$Search.Date, "%y%m%d")`

> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

How can I convert these currently? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use `%Y` as the year part is 4 digits, `%y` is used when it is 2 digit.

```
as.Date(d7$Search.Date, "%Y%m%d")
```

For example

```
as.Date("20150122", "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2015-01-22"
```

For more info regarding the `format`, check `?strptime`

Comment: Ah, and we have to convert the variables to factors, right? Because "20150122" is stored as an `int` right now.

Comment: @user122514  YOu can wrap it with `as.character` i.e. `as.Date(as.character(20150122), "%Y%m%d")`